# php asynchronus email?

Tags: php, multithreading, yii

i would like to know.. does Yii supports Asynchronous script execution or multi threading ?

I am in a situation of sending 4 ( to : accounting det, user, created-person, admin) emails when a user update the profile.

I am almost done with my requirement but unfortunately the php page takes too much time, more than 12 seconds to load  which is not a good practice.

can somebody please suggest me someway of achieving this task in less time ? any help would be highly appreciated.

Please note : in each email, content is different from one another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know about yii (at all) but maybe take a look at http://swiftmailer.org/  ? There also seems to be a Yii Extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/swiftmailer/

Comment: _PHP_ does _not_ support threads or asynchronous execution. You can try something with `exec()`.

Comment: it seems that your mail sever(postfix/sendmail) is misconfigured, normally it won't take 12 secs to send just 4 mails. If not sure what to do try cronjob to send emails.

Comment: Can somebody tel me why i cant make the below code section with YII framework ???????????

it works with normal php but in YII i cdnt figure out whats wrong..

please take a look at the post i have put in yii forum.

any help is much appreciated.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36021-fsockopen-or-background-postget-methods/page_gopid_173255#entry173255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not support threads but with Pcntl extension it supports process forking. You could create a child process that will send yout emails. I guess you should not use "pcntl_wait" in your case.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Can somebody tel me why i cant make the below code section with YII framework ???????????

it works with normal php but in YII i cdnt figure out whats wrong..

please take a look at the post i have put in yii forum.

any help is much appreciated.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36021-fsockopen-or-background-postget-methods/page_gopid_173255#entry173255